# Notification wtih AlarmManager in fragment

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager

Have a trouble trying to get an alarm manager to work with a notification inside. This is to give the user of the app, a notification on a certain point.

My alarm is setup inside a fragment, with the code as following.

```
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getContext(), DeviceBootReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getContext(), 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        int hour = Integer.parseInt(vars.getShowRapport().getFinishTime().split(":")[0]);
        int min = Integer.parseInt(vars.getShowRapport().getFinishTime().split(":")[1]);

        vars.getShowRapport().getFinishDate().setHours(hour);
        vars.getShowRapport().getFinishDate().setMinutes(min);

        long futureInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()+1000*60;
        //long futureInMillis = vars.getShowRapport().getFinishDate().getTime();
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, futureInMillis, pendingIntent);

        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.makeRapportFragment,fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

In my manifest i have

`<receiver android:process=":remote" android:name=".DeviceBootReceiver">/receiver>`

And finally in my receiver called DeviceBootReceiver i have.

```
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ejservicebookincon)
                    .setContentTitle("Rapport finishing")
                    .setContentText("Rapport on item should be done.");
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, ServiceRapportMain.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    // Add as notification
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify(0, builder.build());
```

Don't know where my problem is, and my receiver never seems to be activated, so can't check if that part work as of yet. Would like help if someone could point out, where my problem is. And just as a heads up i'm working in Android Studio.

Comment: Why are you using `android:process=":remote"`?

Comment: Using that as the example i followed used it, but removing it did nothing, but did find my error. I have used AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP where then one i should have used here was AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP

Answer (score 0):

As i wrote in the comment above, the error i had was that i used AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP where then one i should have used here was AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP